# Problemas com funcão do mongoose (nodeJS)

Tags: mongodb, express.js

Olá, estou tendo problemas com uma mini-api de aprendizado que eu estou fazendo, não sou usuário avançado, mas já mexo com NodeJS faz tempo, resolvi criar uma mini-api sem olhar tutorial, apenas docs, porém me deparei com esse erro, e não consegui entender, creio que seja fácil, então para economizar tempo resolvi vir aqui perguntar.

O erro que eu gostaria de pelo menos entender é este, que é referente ao index.js na linha do Produto.create que eu não entendi porque deu errado, e para olhar o resto do código,eu subi para o GitHUB todos os arquivos, LINK: https://github.com/Raisler/expressApi-example [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo erro `Product.create is not a function` me parece bem claro de que o erro está no módulo `ProdutoM`, não no `index`.

Em `ProdutoM` você está exportando o seu módulo da seguinte maneira:

```
module.exports = ("Produto", ProdutoSchema)
```

Imagino que a sua intuição seria o seguinte:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Produto", ProdutoSchema)
```

Agora, mesmo que você esteja exportando o módulo corretamente, seu código ainda não irá funcionar, pois você não está estabelecendo uma conexão com o banco de dados. Lembre-se de importar o `.src/db/database.js` no seu `index`. Só a ação de importar o módulo já é o bastante, pois você só precisa que o código nesse módulo seja executado ao iniciar o servidor.

E finalmente, lembre-se de enviar uma resposta para o usuário depois do `Produto.create()`. Não há a necessidade de utilizar `produto.save()` nesse caso, o `create` já salva no banco de dados, `save` só seria necessário se você tivesse criado ou alterado uma instancia de `mongoose.model` e precisa-se atualiza-la no banco de dados:

```
app.post('/registro', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Produto.create(req.body);
        res.send('ok');
    } catch {
        res.status(500).send('erro');
    }
})
```